# How to resolve InvalidOperationException while adding a WPF UI Element to the Winform Grid Control Panel?

Tags: wpf, winforms, wpf-controls, vsto, invalidoperationexception

We have a CRM Add-in for Microsoft Outlook, which displays a custom task pane which has a WinForm control inside a WPF form/control as one of its functionalities. But, since after Version 1812 and the latest update to Office 365 pro plus installations, in some of the client machines we have been facing the following error/exceptions and form doesn't show or load:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Hosted HWND must be a child window
>   of the specified parent.    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildWindow(HandleRef hwndParent)
>   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildOrReparentWindow()    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.OnSourceChanged(Object sender,
>   SourceChangedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.SourceChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
>   RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.PresentationSource.UpdateSourceOfElement(DependencyObject
>   doTarget, DependencyObject doAncestor, DependencyObject doOldParent)
>   at
>   System.Windows.PresentationSource.OnVisualAncestorChanged(DependencyObject
>   uie, AncestorChangedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.OnVisualAncestorChanged(Object sender,
>   AncestorChangedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(DependencyObject
>   e, AncestorChangedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject
>   oldParent)    at System.Windows.Media.Visual.AddVisualChild(Visual
>   child)    at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.ConnectChild(Int32
>   index, Visual value) at
>   System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.Add(Visual visual) at
>   System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement
>   element) at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(UIElement
>   element)

Basically, the code fails while embedding and displaying the WPF form. The exact code snippet causing the issue is as follows:

```
 public void DisplayForm(System.Windows.Forms.Control form)
        {
            // Adapt WinForm Form Control to WPF           
            System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost wfh = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
            wfh.Child = form;
            wfh.Margin = new Thickness(0);

            // Display WPF Form            
            DisplayForm(wfh);            
        }


        // Embed a WPF Control       
        public void DisplayForm(UIElement form)
        {
            HostPanel.Children.Clear(); 

    //***Below line throws an exception***
            HostPanel.Children.Add(form);
        }
```

In the above code,

**HostPanel**: *System.Windows.Controls.Grid*

**Children**: *UIElementCollection Panel*

Also, the HostPanel or the grid has been used/placed in the XAML like below :

```
<Grid>

<!-- Form Panel -->
<Grid Name="HostPanel" Margin="0,50,0,0">
</Grid>
```

And, in the XAML code partial class:

1. We are assigning the Winform control as a child of the WPF.
2. Then, we are trying to add the WPF form/UIElement in the UIElementCollection Panel of the grid control.

It is really difficult to narrow down to the exact root cause of the issue when everything was working as expected and just after pushing the updates to the Microsoft Office, the errors/exceptions are being seen.

Any help or pointers towards resolving the issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**

### Update

**

This issue seems to be due to Microsoft introduced [Office support for High DPI](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-support-for-high-definition-displays-6720ca0e-be59-41f6-b629-1369f549279d)

And the issue could be fixed inside Outlook by selecting "Optimize for compatibility" in Display Settings on the bottom status bar or in User Interface options under General Outlook options:

[Image for the setting/configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdz38.png)

However, is there a way to make the above-mentioned code DPI aware and to get the form controls rendered without any issue?

Also, from this [MSDN Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/ddpi/handle-high-dpi-and-dpi-scaling-in-your-office-solution#top-level-window-management), I learn that it might not be possible as child parented to Office window cannot respond to DPI scaling. But, any further inputs on the same would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have both functions named the same? Could is possibly calling one of them recursively?

Comment: The method signature is different, so it works without recursive calls.